# How to test if a web browser is on a URL c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, browser

So I'm trying to use

```
if (webBrowser1.Url == google.com)
{
 // code here
}
```

But that doesn't work. So how can I successfully do this?

Comment: what kind of application is this? is it winforms? `webBrowser1` is a webBrowser control?

Comment: Yes, its a windows form application.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over that "url" element you'll see that is of type uri.  So you can't just try to compare it to a string (though you aren't even comparing it to a string because you didn't put it in quotes).  You could try:  `if(webBrowser1.Url.ToString().Contains("google.com"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`webBrowser.Url`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url(v=vs.110).aspx) Gets or sets the URL associated with the webBrowser. unfortunately which is not a string as you expected. it is of type `system.Uri` So you need to get the string representation of the URL to compare it with another string. For that you can use `webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri`(or you can use `webBrowser1.Url.ToString()` which gives you the URL string Corresponds to the `system.Uri`. then perform the comparison like the following:

```
if (webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://google.com")
{
 // code here
}
```

Or this too help you

```
if (webBrowser1.Url.Host=="google.com")
{
  // code here
}
```